# Asterisk-Java support for driving DTMF to a MeetMe conference?

Tags: java, asterisk, digit, dtmf

I have a Java app that accesses Asterisk as a manager via Asterisk-Java.  The app has a dialer interface, which I can use to dial number strings and play single digits to extensions defined in sip.conf.  Now, I am trying to figure out how to drive a digit from this dialer (using A-J PlayDtmfAction) into a MeetMe conference, to enter a PIN as requested by MeetMe.  In my DialPlan, I have an ext-meetme context that supports confRoom 1024...

```
>[ Context 'ext-meetme' created by 'pbx_config' ]
>  '1024' =>         1. Macro(user-callerid,)                      [pbx_config]
>                    2. Set(MEETME_ROOMNUM=1024)                   [pbx_config]
>                    3. Set(MAX_PARTICIPANTS=2)                    [pbx_config]
>                    4. Set(MEETME_MUSIC=${MOHCLASS})              [pbx_config]
>                    5. Gosub(sub-record-check,s,1(conf,1024,always))
>[pbx_config]
>                    6. GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "ANSWER"]?READPIN)
>[pbx_config]
>                    7. Answer()                                   [pbx_config]
>                    8. Wait(1)                                    [pbx_config]
>                    9. Set(PINCOUNT=0)                            [pbx_config]
>     [READPIN]      10. Read(PIN,enter-conf-pin-number,,,,)       [pbx_config]
>
><THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO INJECT A DTMF STRING>
>
>                    11. GotoIf($[x${PIN} = x123]?USER)            [pbx_config]
>                    12. GotoIf($[x${PIN} = x321]?ADMIN)           [pbx_config]
>                    13. Set(PINCOUNT=$[${PINCOUNT}+1])            [pbx_config]
>                    14. GotoIf($[${PINCOUNT}>3]?h)                [pbx_config]
>                    15. Playback(conf-invalidpin)                 [pbx_config]
>                    16. Goto(READPIN)                             [pbx_config]
>     [ADMIN]        17. Set(MEETME_OPTS=aAoTqcIMsr)               [pbx_config]
>                    18. Goto(STARTMEETME,1)                       [pbx_config]
>     [USER]         19. Set(MEETME_OPTS=oTqcIMsr)                 [pbx_config]
>                    20. Goto(STARTMEETME,1)                       [pbx_config]
```

You can see the spot where I need to play the PIN to MeetMe.  I am not sure what [READPIN] signifies here.  When I turn on Asterisk CLI verbose mode, I can see that I get to number 10 above.  Then a timeout occurs and Asterisk says the user did not enter any digits.

The problem is I cannot define properly to PlayDtmfAction the correct destination channelID to play the digit to.  What works is playing a digit to a real extension like SIP/100-00034bc2.  There is no such channel for MeetMe.  If I query the calling channel's info while at this point of the dialplan, it shows the destination as 1024@from-internal:1.  I try that with PlayDtmfAction but Asterisk returns error.  I have also tried things like 1024@ext-meetme, Local/1024, Local/1024@ext-meetme:1, and many others.

I heard of using AGI, but also read that AGI should not be used for blocking apps like MeetMe.  If I can use AGI I'd love to learn how.

I use a system that is configured by FreePBX, if that matters.  My app is separate from FreePBX.

Any help appreciated and I'll be glad to get any info requested.

Thanks!

Greg in MA

Comment: Hi again,This is what I see in Asterisk CLI (verbose=20) when I run my test:

Comment: [2013-06-03 17:47:17] VERBOSE[23662] file.c: -- <SIP/100-000000a5> Playing 'enter-conf-pin-number.gsm' (language 'en')

[2013-06-03 17:47:29] VERBOSE[23662] app_read.c: -- User entered nothing.
[2013-06-03 17:47:29] VERBOSE[23662] pbx.c: -- Executing [1024@from-internal:11] GotoIf("SIP/100-000000a5", "0?USER") in new stack

Comment: Not think anybody wiil debug your asterisk instead of you. [READPIN] is label in dialplan. Easiest way for you is just skip pin -see metmee app. AGI will not help.

Comment: Thanks Arheops.  Unfortunately the Asterisk config is out of my control, so I need to handle this situation if the customer configures their MeetMe room to require a PIN.

Comment: there are no easy answer. read docs or hire expert. sorry, i can't help you in 15 minutes, so cant' help you at all.

Comment: It seems like using A-J originateToApplication() could help here?  I use Originate() now for all calls, including dialing into a conference room.